# how to store property value in jcr content level with out select radio button in touch ui Dialog in AEM 6.3

Tags: aem, aem-6

For checkbox we have uncheckedValue "false" property

Once drag and drop component open dialog with out checked checkedbox and closing dialog i am able to store property value in jcr node

How to do for radio button to store property.

[Default value for radio button in AEM 6.2 touch UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44377846/default-value-for-radio-button-in-aem-6-2-touch-ui)
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27520377/how-to-create-a-radio-button-in-aem-6-touch-dialog)

Comment: <text sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/form/checkbox" jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" name="./test" value="true" **uncheckedValue="false"** text="test for checkbox" />

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, Are you looking to have one of the radio buttons be checked by default when opening the dialog for the first time?

Comment: thanks for reply   by default radio button unchecked when open dialog , but I need to store property jcr node.  for radio button I provide property  name = •/test.  jcr node store data will be   test  "false"

Comment: You can add a property 'checked="{boolean}true" to the default radio button you want to be checked by default which has the vlaue "false", this way if the user opens the dialog first time, then submits, the jcr value will be "false"

Comment: If i add 'checked="{boolean}true" this property  ,when i open the dialog it's by default check the radio button. for example below checkbox  i am able to stroe property in jcr node with out check checkbox.   
<text sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/f‌​orm/checkbox" jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" name="./test" value="true" uncheckedValue="false" text="test for checkbox" />

Comment: uncheckedValue="false"    if add this property i am able to store property in jcr node in checkbox ,this one is not working radio button